# Separating style from content in form design with vba - Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Having done a bit of web design in the past, I found the benefit of using style sheets to make changes to multiple pages at once. I have tried to incorporate this into the development of my access apps by creating modules that style forms and running these routines on the forms On Open event. If I need to make any changes to, for example, a forms header background colour I can do this in the coding as opposed to having to change each form individually.

I'm sure I'm not the first to do so, but I was wondering if any body else does this and if there are any pitfalls that I may need to be aware of?

Comment: I'm doing it in hte app I'm working on now. No pitfalls of which I'm aware.

Comment: I've done it, too. It's pretty much part of my standard toolbox in the last few years, particularly when I'm taking over a legacy project and need to get buy-in from the user population. Often, changing the appearance to something really attractive and "modern" makes them think it's a better app (even if nothing has changed except cosmetics). Doing it the way you describe is the fastest way to get up and running with that kind of thing.

Comment: cheers @RolandTumble @David-W-Fenton, reassuring to know that I'm using the correct methodologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people do this and there are no pitfalls of which you need to be aware.